# How to separate columns in csv data joined by ';' expression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-cleaning

df.head() ....> shows

```
Wicket_Type;Bowler;Bowler_Type;Ground
0   caught;BW Hilfenhaus;right-arm pace;Melbourne
1   lbw;BW Hilfenhaus;right-arm pace;Melbourne
2   caught;PM Siddle;right-arm pace;Sydney
3   lbw;JL Pattinson;right-arm pace;Sydney
4   caught;PM Siddle;right-arm pace;Perth
5   caught;PM Siddle;right-arm pace;Perth
6   lbw;BW Hilfenhaus;right-arm pace;Adelaide
7   caught;PM Siddle;right-arm pace;Mohali
8   caught;JR Hazlewood;right-arm pace;Brisbane
9   caught;RJ Harris;right-arm pace;Melbourne
10  caught;RJ Harris;right-arm pace;Sydney
11  lbw;JR Hazlewood;right-arm pace;Bengaluru
12  caught;PJ Cummins;right-arm pace;Ranchi
13  caught;PJ Cummins;right-arm pace;Adelaide
14  caught;PJ Cummins;right-arm pace;Perth
15  caught;PJ Cummins;right-arm pace;Melbourne
16  caught;JR Hazlewood;right-arm pace;Sydney
17  caught;NM Lyon;right-arm spin;Chennai
18  caught;GJ Maxwell;right-arm spin;Hyderabad (De...
19  lbw;NM Lyon;right-arm spin;Delhi
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv('path', sep=';')`?

Answer (score 0):

specify the seperator in the `pd.read_csv` command.

In your case `sep=';'`